# BinaryWrite negative numbers

Tags: export, import, data, binary

```
testList = {1, 2, 3, 4};
file = "test1";
BinaryWrite[file, testList];
BinaryReadList[file]
Close[file];
```

Gives

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Cool... but

```
testList = {1, 2, 3, -4};
file = "test1";
BinaryWrite[file, testList];
BinaryReadList[file]
Close[file];
```

Results in

```
BinaryWrite::nocoerce: -4 cannot be coerced to the specified format. >>
```

I have to Read and Write Data files that are 5GB large and they have pos and negativ values. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default type is an unsigned integer. You need to specify a suitable type, eg:

```
testList = {1, 2, 3, -4};
file = "test1";
BinaryWrite[file, testList, "Integer8"];
BinaryReadList[file, "Integer8"]
Close[file];
```

Note the read needs to know the type as well.  See `BinaryRead` for the list of types. (`Integer8` is only good for values in the range -128 to 127 of course )

Comment: Do you know whats the identifier for double?

Comment: Just found it...  "Real64" Thanks!